# Not showing amazon echo dot as output or input device in ubuntu sound setting after connecting through bluetooth

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, settings

Though bluetooth pairing is successfull with Amazon Echo dot 3rd gen from **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**( Echo says Now connected to `<my machine's name>`), The device is not listed in the sound setting as input/output device, So the problem is ,sound is coming from the inbuilt speaker and not from the echo device.

**Things that I've already tried**

- connecting/disconnecting device multiple times
- bluetooth pairing while laptop is playing some music(on youtube)

not really sure which command / logs to be checked for this issue. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of googling and trying out many commands, finally [this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/689281/3)  solved my issue

Reinstalling bluetooth modules and rebooting worked out for me.

```
sudo apt install bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

```
 wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
```

```
sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
```

```
 sudo modprobe -r btusb
```

```
 sudo modprobe btusb
```